# Looping through a PHP object

Tags: php, mysql, loops, object

I did a query in php and all the results are stored in an object. For example

```
$query = "select * from some_table";
$sth = $dbc->query($query);
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Therefore the results of the query is stored in `$results` and I have a property called `name`. How can I now loop through this object `$results` to change all the values of a certain property `name` of the object.

Comment: You can see the structure of the object with `var_dump($object)`.
This way you can know how to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `name` is a public property:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
  $results[$i]->name = ...; 
}
```